# Cap the amount of RAM an fio command uses?

Tags: linux, multithreading, io

I am trying to run multiple fio threads synchronously, and I'm running out of RAM on my computer as I increase the number of threads. It seems like each fio thread takes around 200MB of RAM. That being said, is there any way to make each thread have a fixed maximum RAM usage? Does setting `lockmem` do what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Setting `lockmem` does NOT do what you want - that option is more for ensuring that fio's memory is "real" (i.e. not swap) and ensuring that said memory can't be swapped out to disk...

Generally speaking, the amount of memory each thread requires scales with how big your blocksize is, the size of your iodepth, whether you are doing things like verification, whether you're creating a bandwidth/latency log etc. There is also a fixed overhead for IPC when using fio in process mode and this latter amount can only be changed by going to [fio source, changing the maximum number of job fio supports](https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/fio-3.3/os/os.h#L170) and then recompiling or by using thread mode.

Sadly, since you didn't include the fio command and job file you are using it's impossible for me to say any more. Sorry!